# Is it possible to have an ipad simulator for windows?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I am developing an application for iPad but in reality i don't have the iPad.So is their any way to perform this task on windows platform without having the iPad.Is it possible to have an ipad simulator for windows?

Your help will surely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Arvind Thakur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Ok, there *are* things like hackintoshs, however I don't think it's worth the while.

Seriously, if you're planning to release an app for iPad, you should have tested it on an actual iPad prior to release. While the iPad Simulator is good, there still are differences - if your app runs on the simulator, that does **not** necessarily mean it will run on the device.

I think I remember that testing on an actual device prior to release is even required in the iOS Developer Terms of Use somewhere.

You'll find nicely priced 16 GB 1st Gen Units at an auction platform of your choice.

Comment: Surely I will buy an ipad later, but for now I just wants to know how to do this using simulators.I have the complete application which is running good on desktop, I also opened that on iPad too but few things like div-scrollbar, showModalDialog object etc not working on iPad as they work on desktop.So I want to know how I can I fix these issue on using my desktop using ipad simulator because I cannot code and develop the app using iPad.Development will be done on desktop but presentation will be done on iPad.

Answer (score 3):

I did this for a project. It's a pain, but it can be done with VMWare, you just emulate Snow Leopard or whatever Mac OS (which you will have to purchase, luckily they are very cheap compared to Windows.) Then from VMWare you run can run XCode, which has a very nice iPad simulator which, while not a perfect simulator, certainly gave me no problems.

Comment: :Is it necessary to use MAC OS? Can we do this using windows?

Comment: No, sorry. You have to do it on Mac, or at least simulated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Safari on Windows to simulate much of the iPad web environment if you're building a web-app, however building a true iPad application will require using Xcode on the Mac.

Comment: Hi Errol, this is an old post, but we're seeing differences between Safari on windows and Safari on the iPad which I was very surprised with. So we're now looking into either buying an ipad or simulators. Are we still at the same point with this where there's no simulator on windows?

Comment: Yes indeed, Apple still only provides Xcode for Mac. There may be some third party tools for Windows that are pretty good but I've not used any. I don't think Apple has updated Safari for Windows in quite some time. The best bet now may be WebKit directly: https://www.webkit.org

Comment: Well, after looking into this more... Webkit doesn't seem like much of an option. You may be better off buying an iPad than going through the trouble of setting up a build of Webkit.